# joomla 2.5 JText not working in xml file

Tags: xml, joomla, components

i am going to create a new component.
i am using **JText::_()** method for translating strings in my **xml form files**.
i have a field type="list" with two options.

how can i use JText string keys in the value part of option fields in the xml forms to be translated?

i used a code like this but the COM_MYCOMPONENT_KEY_VALUE didn't translated!

```
<field type="list" ...>
<option value="COM_MYCOMPONENT_KEY_VALUE">COM_MYCOMPONENT_KEY</option>
</field>
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you defined the translation for this string in your language file?

Comment: @Lodder Yes, I think it doesn't translate because it comes between double quotes! but i don't know the solution!

Comment: The double quotes is fine. Simply ensure you have defined the translation in the language file. Take a look at this: http://docs.joomla.org/Specification_of_language_files

Answer (score 0):

Even if this would work, I think you may be missing the point of translating the field value.

This should be not a language specific value, so that you can still refer to it, no matter what language you have on.

The point in Joomla is not to translate all the strings / values. Also language strings should not be used for configuration purposes.

Comment: I figured out the point. i wanted to show the string values to end users in the frontend directly, instead of showing 1,2,... .by the way i think i have to use a mapping function or create a mapping table in the database and use that to show strings.